# how to do aggregation query with pagination in druid(Druid is a column-oriented, distributed data store). Does it support query with offset?

Tags: druid

how to do aggregation query with pagination in druid(Druid is a column-oriented, distributed data store). Does it support query with offset?
I have searched but did not get anything so posting here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do pagination with select queries. See below druid documentation link for details - http://druid.io/docs/latest/querying/select-query.html

eg. you can send below query -

```
 {
       "queryType": "select",
       "dataSource": "wikipedia",
       "descending": "false",
       "dimensions":[],
       "metrics":[],
       "granularity": "all",
       "intervals": [
         "2013-01-01/2013-01-02"
       ],
       "pagingSpec":{"pagingIdentifiers": {}, "threshold":5}
     }

Result - 

[{
  "timestamp" : "2013-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "result" : {
    "pagingIdentifiers" : {
      "wikipedia_2012-12-29T00:00:00.000Z_2013-01-10T08:00:00.000Z_2013-01-10T08:13:47.830Z_v9" : 4
    },
    "events" : [ {
      "segmentId" : "wikipedia_editstream_2012-12-29T00:00:00.000Z_2013-01-10T08:00:00.000Z_2013-01-10T08:13:47.830Z_v9",
      "offset" : 0,
      "event" : {
        "timestamp" : "2013-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "robot" : "1",
        "namespace" : "article",
        "anonymous" : "0",
        "unpatrolled" : "0",
        "page" : "11._korpus_(NOVJ)",
        "language" : "sl",
        "newpage" : "0",
        "user" : "EmausBot",
        "count" : 1.0,
        "added" : 39.0,
        "delta" : 39.0,
        "variation" : 39.0,
        "deleted" : 0.0
      }
    }, {
      "segmentId" : "wikipedia_2012-12-29T00:00:00.000Z_2013-01-10T08:00:00.000Z_2013-01-10T08:13:47.830Z_v9",
      "offset" : 1,
      "event" : {
        "timestamp" : "2013-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "robot" : "0",
        "namespace" : "article",
        "anonymous" : "0",
        "unpatrolled" : "0",
        "page" : "112_U.S._580",
        "language" : "en",
        "newpage" : "1",
        "user" : "MZMcBride",
        "count" : 1.0,
        "added" : 70.0,
        "delta" : 70.0,
        "variation" : 70.0,
        "deleted" : 0.0
      }
    }, {
      "segmentId" : "wikipedia_2012-12-29T00:00:00.000Z_2013-01-10T08:00:00.000Z_2013-01-10T08:13:47.830Z_v9",
      "offset" : 2,
      "event" : {
        "timestamp" : "2013-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "robot" : "0",
        "namespace" : "article",
        "anonymous" : "0",
        "unpatrolled" : "0",
        "page" : "113_U.S._243",
        "language" : "en",
        "newpage" : "1",
        "user" : "MZMcBride",
        "count" : 1.0,
        "added" : 77.0,
        "delta" : 77.0,
        "variation" : 77.0,
        "deleted" : 0.0
      }
    }, {
      "segmentId" : "wikipedia_2012-12-29T00:00:00.000Z_2013-01-10T08:00:00.000Z_2013-01-10T08:13:47.830Z_v9",
      "offset" : 3,
      "event" : {
        "timestamp" : "2013-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "robot" : "0",
        "namespace" : "article",
        "anonymous" : "0",
        "unpatrolled" : "0",
        "page" : "113_U.S._73",
        "language" : "en",
        "newpage" : "1",
        "user" : "MZMcBride",
        "count" : 1.0,
        "added" : 70.0,
        "delta" : 70.0,
        "variation" : 70.0,
        "deleted" : 0.0
      }
    }, {
      "segmentId" : "wikipedia_2012-12-29T00:00:00.000Z_2013-01-10T08:00:00.000Z_2013-01-10T08:13:47.830Z_v9",
      "offset" : 4,
      "event" : {
        "timestamp" : "2013-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "robot" : "0",
        "namespace" : "article",
        "anonymous" : "0",
        "unpatrolled" : "0",
        "page" : "113_U.S._756",
        "language" : "en",
        "newpage" : "1",
        "user" : "MZMcBride",
        "count" : 1.0,
        "added" : 68.0,
        "delta" : 68.0,
        "variation" : 68.0,
        "deleted" : 0.0
      }
    } ]
  }
} ]
```

Result comes with pagingIdentifiers which you can pass in next query.

Please note it doesn't work with top N queries as of now.

Update -

For top N queries or aggregated results, there is currently no direct way of fetching paginated results, but you can use bigger threshold and limits and exclude the previous results at client side.

Comment: Thanks @mdoera but Select queries return raw Druid rows. I want pagination with aggregation, because its not a good to show 1000 of rows at one page after aggregation, isn't it? Can you suggest something better for this use case?

Comment: have updated the answer with some approach, for pagination with the aggregation output.